# Regex - choosing only separate words in a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm new to Regex and I'd like to perform the following operation in Pandas:

- In Series `s`, I have the following words `foo`, `bar`, `baz`.
- Is DataFrame `df` I have

```
index string

0 foobright foo barber baz bare

1 foo bar barret bazar
```

I'd like to remove all occurrences of `foo`, `bar`, `baz` only if they are separate words in the DataFrame `df`.

The Output I'm looking for is a DataFrame `out`:

```
index string

0 foobright barber bare

1 barret bazar
```

I cannot figure out the regex to perform this operation.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Regex here is not necessary, only split values by whitespaces, filter by `Series` and join back in generator with `join`:

```
s = pd.Series(['foo','bar','baz'])
df['string'] = [' '.join(x for x in a.split() if x not in s.tolist()) for a in df['string']]

print (df)
                  string
0  foobright barber bare
1           barret bazar
```

Or use lambda function:

```
s = pd.Series(['foo','bar','baz'])
f = lambda a: ' '.join(x for x in a.split() if x not in s.tolist())
df['string'] = df['string'].apply(f)

print (df)
                  string
0  foobright barber bare
1           barret bazar
```

Comment: does your generator change if it is a DataFrame instead of just a string? I updated my question to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

in Notepad++ find with following regular expression

```
[$\s]foo|bar|baz[\s$]
```